# Catch HTTP error in bluebird promisified request

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, node-request

Using `bluebird.promisify` around the `request` module, all HTTP errors (non-200 status) are being swallowed.

Consider the following contrived example:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var request = bluebird.promisify(require("request")); 

function makeRequest(options) {
    return request(options)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.body;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return error;
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            return error;
        })
}
```

For a successful request, resolution works as expected:

```
makeRequest({...}).then(function(body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

For HTTP requests that error (eg 404, 500 status etc), the promise is never rejected, and neither the `catch` or `error` blocks are executed.

Why is this?

Comment: 404 or 500 response status it's not request error, it's calling server error. You must check `res.statusCode` in first `then` block and reject promise when status is not 200.